# which delegate method will call while clicking device close button

Tags: objective-c, ipad

On clicking device close button.  Which method will call.

I launch the application and navigated to other view controller.  i displaying 
popOverViewController and closing the application.  again relaunching application. its redirecting to home screen and displaying popOverviewController.

```
But I want to know when clicking the device close button which method will call?
```

So i can dismiss my popoverviewcontroller there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Probably you need `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`.

Be sure to check the docs for your view controller's `viewWillDisappear` etc also.

Comment: I used ViewWillDisappears  [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
 Called this its not working for me